# What are my options to get thousands firestore or BigQuery rows in less than 2 secondes using JavaScript/TypeScript?

Tags: performance, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, query-optimization

I'm trying to optimize ~10k data-rows load time, here is my setup :

2 Firebase projects : **A** & **B**

**In project A**
I have a firestore database with a "entries" collection.

**In project B**
I have a web app that needs those data to display a variety of charts.
In time of writing, the web app's fetching data this way :

- Web App calls a CallableFunction
- This CallableFunction connects to project **A**'s firestore using firebase-admin package and a service-account key file.

**Problem**

- Querying times are bad, around 4 seconds for less than 10k documents... even with indexes.
  It's surely possible to query thousands of documents in less than 2s, am I wrong ?

---

**BigQuery**
So, I tried to use BigQuery to replace firestore in cloud function **B**.

- The firestore database in project **A** sync "entries" collection documents to BigQuery using the [firebase-firestore-bigquery-export extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-bigquery-export).
- This extension sends document "changes" on JSON format in a changelog "table" (called changelog) and reconstruct the firestore schema (or kind of) with 2 "views" (called schema).

I tried 2 ways of querying BigQuery :

- `bigquery.query()`
- `bigquery.createQueryJob()`

Both makes ~9s per request, varying a bit depending on rows count fetched (1k | 10k).

But when I tried the `bigquery.createQueryJob()` with the `destination` option set, timings are amazing !
If I understand correctly, when specifying this `destination` option, it creates a "permanent table" and populate it with data got from query ?
And because I'm querying directly a "table", it's quicker than querying a view constructed from another view, itself constructed from a table ?

Ok so, anyway, timings are perfect, but if I call the function again, it throws with error saying the table already exists.
So I fixed it by calling `bigquery.createQueryJob()` only when destination table does NOT exists and querying with `destinationTable.query()` when table already exists.

This now locks me to the dataset queried the first time I called the function.
Do I need to sync this table regularly with a scheduled query maybe ?
It seems complicated to just query my real-time data.

- Do I missed anything more simple/efficient ?
- Do I moving in the right direction ?

EDIT : When I said "timings are amazing with destination option set", I mean, every queries AFTER the first one who's actually creating the permanent table, so this way of querying seems to not be the best one as it forces me to "update regularly this table" to have consistent amazing data-load times, and it could be a solution, but I want a more "direct" way if it's possible. ^^

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas:

1. Use CREATE OR REPLACE syntax in BQ to recreate the table.
2. Use partitioning and clustering in BQ to be more effective.
3. Turn on BI Engine so Bigquery be more effective and fast. [Link](https://medium.com/p/9e2634c84a82).

Comment: Thanks for your ideas, 
 1. I can't do that, I'm querying with a "SELECT" query, using the google NodeJS client library (bigquery.createQueryJob()).
 2. Interesting, I'm digging this way, do you have some tips about it ?
 3. Yeah, I'm searching a way to optimize costless before, but should watch this too. ^^

Comment: For #1, just write CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ..... AS SELECT ..........

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try, I also tried the clustering option, adding `useQueryCache: true` and `clustering: { fields: [...] }` to query options, but it throws given `Required parameter is missing` with no more details.. any clue ?